# Threadsafe within a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, forkjoinpool

I'm writing a program, in Java, to simulate a molecular algorithm.  As the molecular algorithm inherently uses concurrency (you can have as many chemical reactions going as needed, as long as you have the chemicals and concentrations to supply them), it requires me to use concurrency.

However, I recently found out that the package I was using for my graph structures is not threadsafe.  I have an ArrayList of graphs set up for each thread.  During computation, a thread modifies its own ArrayList and some of the graphs within it, but I have no code allowing one thread to modify the ArrayList or graphs of any other thread, until it recieves the two ArrayLists from its child threads.

To accomplish this, I'm using ForkJoinPool (My understanding of this is, and please correct me if I'm wrong, is that it divides the task up among two threads which divide the task up among two threads... When the calculations are done in the leaf threads, they return up to their parent thread, and so on, until the roots children return up to it, and the root, if ForkJoinTask, returns the result).

Needless to say, the notable exception to what I want happening is worksteeling.  My question, therefore is, if, with the exceptions of worksteeling and a child thread returning to a parent thread, if no threads interact with any other threads, can a nonthreadsafe object be used in a concurrent application?

Comment: Posts are like code, it needs indentation.

Comment: Threadsafe is threadsafe.  If you're modifying shared data, you have to synchronize.  Maybe a threadsafe version of List is what you want.

Comment: Yes. As long as a non-threadsafe object is used by only one thread, there's no problem. Every server application uses many threads, and each thread uses ArrayList, StringBuilder, and many many non-threadsafe objects, all the time.

Comment: Excellent.  However, would it still be threadsafe if worksteeling happened?

Answer (score 0):

I'd wonder if this process would lend itself well to map/reduce.  The algorithms require concurrency; the physics and chemistry suggest ways to partition the problem.  It might be an easy way to get safe, efficient concurrency.